# Align multi-line section head on the grid

Tags: sectioning, context, context-mkiv, grid-typesetting

**What I want to achieve**

Align the first line of a multi-line section head on the grid and consecutive
lines according to the baseline distance given in the font definition. The
baseline distance of the font used for the section heads does not match the
grid distance.

**What I have so far**

If a section head consists of only one line, then `grid=high` does what I
expect; the first (in fact, the only line) is aligned on the grid. However,
when the head consists of more than one line, the last line is always aligned
on the grid, instead of the first.

**Available documentation**

The [Details manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/details.pdf)
lists several values for `grid` and quite some documentation. But all examples
are single-line heads, unfortunately.

**The code**

```
\setuplayout [grid=yes]
\definefont  [BigFont]  [Bold at 20pt] [24pt]
\setuphead   [section]  [style=\BigFont, grid=high, before={\blank[4*line]}]

\showgrid
\starttext

  \startsection [title=Lorem ipsum dolor]
    \input ward
  \stopsection

  \startsection [title=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit]
    \input ward
  \stopsection

  % Demonstration what I'd like to achieve
  \blank [4*line]
  \startlinecorrection
    \BigFont\raisebox5pt\vbox\bgroup
      3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur\crlf
      \null\kern20pt adipisicing elit\egroup
  \stoplinecorrection
  \input ward

\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot]

The first single-line head is fine. The second is the wrong multi-line head
that wants to be corrected; and the third one is a hack to show how it should
look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach makes two changes to your code:

1. Do not place the headings on grid explicitly: remove the option `grid=high`. (Recommendation based on prior experience.)
2. Stuff headings into a frame with the parameter `location=top`.

The code below remains remarkably robust. Even when dealing with headings that take three lines and more, things will remain on grid. There is, however, one property of your example that it does not account for: if the heading is the first element on a new page, the title will skip the first line. Personally, I prefer that to the heading extending upwards into the header.

```
% macros=mkvi
\setuplayout [grid=yes]
\definefont  [BigFont]  [Bold at 20pt] [24pt]

\unprotect

\newdimen\section_frame_width
\unexpanded\def\section_command#number#title{%
  \section_frame_width\hsize%% we need to calculate the remaining
  \setbox\scratchbox\hbox{#number\space}%% horizontal space
  \advance\section_frame_width by -\wd\scratchbox
  #number\space
  \framed[
    width=\section_frame_width,%% “local” or “fit” doesn’t work
    before=,
    location=top,
    frame=on,%% comment this for production
    align=right,]{#title}%
}

\setuphead   [section]  [
  style=\BigFont,
  after=,
  % grid=high,
  before={\blank[2*line]},
  command=\section_command,
]
\protect

\showgrid

\starttext

  \startsection [title=Lorem ipsum dolor]
    \input ward
  \stopsection

  \dorecurse{4}{%
    \startsection [title=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit]
      \input ward \stopsection %% two lines
    \startsection [title=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
                         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit]
      \input ward \stopsection %% three
    \startsection [title=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
                         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
                         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit]
      \input ward \stopsection %% five
  }

\stoptext
```

[image: first line of structure title on grid]

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution is not (or no longer) working for me. I had to swap `def` for `define`.

```
\setuplayout [grid=yes]
\definefont  [BigFont]  [Bold at 20pt] [24pt]

\unprotect
\newdimen\section_frame_width
\define[2]\section_command{%
  \section_frame_width\hsize             % we need to calculate the remaining
  \setbox\scratchbox\hbox{#1\space} % horizontal space
  \advance\section_frame_width by -\wd\scratchbox
  #1\space
  \framed [
       width=\section_frame_width,
      before=,
    location=top,
       align=right,]{#2}%
}

\setuphead [section] [
    style=\BigFont,
    after=,
   before={\blank[2*line]},
  command=\section_command,
]
\protect

\showgrid
\starttext
  \startsection [title=Lorem ipsum dolor]
    \input ward
  \stopsection

  \dorecurse{4}{%
    \startsection [title=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit]
      \input ward
    \stopsection}
\stoptext
```

Comment: I edited the previous answer to make the macro unexpandable. It should work now

Comment: @Aditya Can you also edit the wiki? The same macro is presented there as a solution, too. https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Grid_typesetting

Comment: @TheoShmitz Done